# Need To Call Struts Action Class Method Upon selecting radio button

Tags: javascript, struts2

I need to call Struts action class method upon selecting one radio button (onclick event) using javascript. the selection of radio button shall be passed as a parameter to the action class method. how can I achieve this? please help me.

```
<s:form style="margin:5px 10;" action="searchAction" method="post" name="searchForm">
    <s:radio name="searchType" label="Criteria" 
        list="{'Data Element','Transaction Details'}" requiredLabel="true"
        tooltip="Your Seach will be done depending upon selected criteria" onclick="func();"/>
```

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function func() {
        var b = document.getElementsByName()('searchType').value;
        var sub = document.searchForm.action + '?searchType=' + b;  
        alert(sub);
        document.searchForm.submit();

    }
```

Comment: Have you written this javascript only to pass a parameter to the action?

Answer (score 0):

you can use your javascript call itself to achieve this...submit the form from your javascript function with the value of the selected radio.

```
 function func() {
        var b = document.getElementsByName()('searchType').value;
        document.searchForm.action = "searchAction?searchType=" + b;
        document.searchForm.submit();

    }
```

Comment: Hi Tijo, Thanks for your response. I am very new in the ajax part and do not have any idea how to achieve this. can you please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve this using Ajax. you can try this one

```
 function func()
  {
    var b = document.getElementsByName()('searchType').value;   
    $.ajax({
          url:searchAction,
           type:'get',
          data:{bParam:b}
      });
  }
```

and create a getters and setters in Your action class for `bParam` I hope this may work I did not test this one check ajax tutorials online